# Instantiating a new object to receive another feature

Tags: java, dereference, custom-object

I've been working on this project so I get to know how to use custom object and custom object types. The problem I'm having is when I write out System.out.println(fe1.TestAuto); it says identifier expected and I don't know why. Im trying to print out the object but it doesn't work. Another problem I'm having is when I want to use the discountValue() method to give a discount on cost it says double cannot be converted to Feature and I don't know why.

The discountValue() method takes in the input from double c and subtracts that with the double d in the Feature Class.

Here's my code below. Could someone try to help me.

```
public class Auto
{
    public String name;
    public double size;
    public Auto(String s, double sz){
        name = s;
        size = sz;
    }
    //step 2: method showFeature()
    public Feature showFeature(Feature f){
        
        System.out.println("The feature " +f+" costs: "+f.cost);
        
    }
    public Feature discountValue(String s, double c, double d){
    //Step 3: method to give discount on cost
        
        double z = c - d.cost;
    
        return z;
    }
}
```

```
public class TestAuto
{
   public static void main(String args[]){
    //instantiate an Auto object
    Auto at = new Auto("AMG", 73.5);
    //instantiate a Feature object
    Feature fe = new Feature("Leather Seat", 3000);
    //execute method addFeature with Feature object
    at.showFeature(fe);
    //prepare a new Feature object for receving information
    Feature fe1 = new Feature("", 0);
    //Run method discountValue with a feature and a new value
    fe1 = at.discountValue("GPS", 15000, 0.2);
    //print out the object
    System.out.println(fe1);
   }
}
```

```
public class Feature
{
    public String name;
    public double cost;
    public Feature(String s, double d){
        //step 1
        name = s;
        cost = d;
    }
    //step 4
    System.out.println(fe1.TestAuto);
}
```

Comment: Class Feature doesn't have a field TestAuto.

Answer (score 0):

> `double z = c - d.cost;`

`d` is of type `double`. It doesn't have a `cost` field. In fact, it is a primitive, it cannot be dereferenced in the first place (putting a dot after a double is an instant compiler error).

> (In Feature.java) `System.out.println(fe1.TestAuto);`

You can't write this here; inside a class def, you can define fields, methods, constructors, initializers, and inner types. But not actual code (when would it run?) - and that's actual code, thus, not legal. Put it in a method or a constructor or some such.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `System.out.println(fe1.TestAuto);` (your step 4) because it isn't in a method of your class `Feature`. If you remove this line, the rest works (just remove `.cost` from `d.cost`.

And I don't understand why you call your class `TestAuto`, who is your main.

Comment: thank you for all the tips but I removed the .cost from d and it says on return z incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Feature. what do I do?>

Comment: Oh yes sorry I can recommend following correction: step2 `public void` instead of `public Feature` because you return nothing, just print something. step 3 if you want to return a `Feature` change `return z` with `return new Feature(s,z)` and you will need to `import class Feature` or something like that.